# Update zoom state in d3 v4 after manually setting translation and scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This has probably been asked many times but as a bloody noob in d3 I could not get a clear solution.

I have a map with points spread on it. When I click a point I want to zoom and pan to it. So far so good but when I try to drag and or zoom it again, it reset's to zoomIdentity not keeping the values I set manually.

EDIT: here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/brunofenzl/pen/pLxbjZ

The relevant parts of my code:

```
// zoom initialization
this.zoom = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 2])
      .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on('zoom', this.zoomed);



// zoom listener

Map.prototype.zoomed = function zoomed() {
    if (d3.event) {
      this.view.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
    }
  }


// the function that zooms in
  Map.prototype.selectFeature = function selectFeature(el) {

    this.active = d3.select(el);

    const bounds = this.active.node().getBBox();

    const dx = bounds.width;
    const dy = bounds.height;
    const x = bounds.x + (bounds.width / 2);
    const y = bounds.y + (bounds.height / 2);

    const scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / this.width, dy / this.height)));
    const translate = [(this.width / 2) - (scale * x), (this.height / 2) - (scale * y)];

    this.view.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");

    return null;
  }
```

I have been trying different solutions for two days now but could not get it working.

Any help more than appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time I found a solution.
In my selectFeature function, instead of setting the transform attribute directly, I should update the cached zoom state. The upside of this solution is that this will trigger the zoom event that will update the UI in the zoomed function already set up.

Working example here: https://codepen.io/brunofenzl/pen/zWmoWJ

To update the cached transform, I used the d3.zoomIdentity as stated in the [readme](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom-transforms)

```
var t = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(x, y).scale(k);
```

So the modified code in my case is:

```
this.view.transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(
    this.zoom.transform, 
    d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale)
  );
```

The downside of this technique is that Extent constraints dont work anymore as expected, so if your extent is less than your new zoom for example, next time you drag or zoom, the zoom will jump to the next possible zoom value allowed by your extent. I solved this for now disabling zoom extent.
I hope this helps others.